# Android Tutorial, Back Stack

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

I have written one simple Android Tetris application. After it I decided to read the dev tutorial. It is time to start.

So, reading about `Back Stack`, I was surprised to find this in the tutorial:

> The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" queue mechanism

"Last in and first out" and "queue" I am fully confident these are different things, I mean "stack" and "queue". Is it a mistake in the tutorial or did the writer want to say something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the obvious possibilities in the Queue being double-ended, I think it's just a (perhaps intentional) mix of English and Programming lingo in that sentence.

When I read that sentence:

> The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" queue mechanism

I understand the "queue mechanism" in plain English, not programming, as in the definition given by the Merriam-Webster's ([See #3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queue))

Of course, that makes me think that document was proof-read by a non-technical fellow :)

Answer (score 0):

A [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) can be seen as a special form of a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29), a LIFO queue. While a queue is usually associated with FIFO (first in, first out) behavior both data structures are often implemented on top of a [double ended queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque) which supports both operating modes.

Comment: :) I know It, but we can say that queue the special form of stack just a FIFO stack ...

Comment: No, DQueue it is hybrid of two data structure queue and stack

Comment: Well, I wouldn't see Dqueue as a hybrid in the sense that it combines the two data structures to something bigger. It is rather a data structure that allows to be used as a LIFO stack and as a FIFO queue while it doesn't have any noteworthy overhead from supporting both access patterns.

Comment: And on wili you can find just _A stack is a fundamental computer science data structure and can be defined in an abstract_ And nothing about that stack it some sub type of queue, I know that description of LIFO was written in theory of queue, but I know and other from a lot of algorithms books, that stack it is abstrack structure and queue too.

Comment: I it call as hybrid, and what does it mean? It means that dqueue contains both functionality from stack and queue. You can get(delete) element from the top and from the bottom ...

Comment: You are correct that queue and stack are well defined on their own in theory. I just tried to explain why it is not unusual to refer to a stack as a special form of a queue and why it would thus not perceived as an error in the documentation of android by many readers.